# Neo4j cypher return node when any one string in it's property array is matched

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

Hi I am new to Neo4j and cypher, and I am trying to perform a probably straightforward match on property array. I am working in the desktop browser

I can create a node with a property array like so:
**CREATE (n:Example {names: ['a', 'b', 'c']})**

I then try to match the names property for any one string like this:
**MATCH (n:Example {names: 'a'}) RETURN n**
But it returns no records

If I match the full array like this:
**MATCH (n:Example {names: ['a', 'b', 'c']}) RETURN n**
Then it returns the node like I want

I know how to match a node's one-string property to an array of strings, but mine is the other way around.
How can I get the node from just matching one string of the node property's array of strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `IN` clause to search within the array:

```
MATCH (n:Example) WHERE 'a' IN n.names RETURN n
```

Comment: Thank you.
Related question, what if the search terms were also an array? Essentially an intersection. For example instead of 'a' it could be ['a', 'b'] where the node is returned if either 'a' or 'b' is present in the property array. Is this a similar method to the answer above or would it require a different approach?